# Problem with with derivative of integral

Tags: integration, derivatives

I know about Libnitz rule but I don't know how we can proof this derivation :

[image]

The  second function 'f' is derivation of 'F' function on 'z'.

This is not a Homework.It is just a part of a question answer in solution manual that I can't understand.
I would be appreciate If You can describe How We can do derivations like this.

Comment: To begin with, I'd like to understand what does $\;Fz(z)\;$ mean, anyway?

Comment: 'f' is probability density function and 'F' is cumulative distribution function.although I think it is not helping to know about F and f in order to  solve the above formulation.

Comment: Ok, $F$ is a CDF, but what does the notation $Fz(z)$ mean?

Comment: we define z=xy . z is new R.V

Comment: I think this question is just about derivation of an integral on a variable.